# How to capture stored procedure query or print output in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure like this

```
  PROCEDURE PRC_ABCD (resultset_out out TYPES.cursorType) 
  AS
      SELECT * FROM ABCD;
  END PRC_ABCD ;
```

And my C# code is like this

```
  string cnn = "connectionstring";

  OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cnn);
  conn.Open();

  var cmd = adapter.CreateSpCommand(con, "PRC_ABCD");
  cmd = adapter.outField(cmd, "resultset_out", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
   using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {

      while (reader.Read())
      {
         yield return Total.FromDataReader(reader, vProductCount, vProductAreaCount, vMonitoredByCount, customerCount);
      }
   }
```

My question is how do I get to see the results of `PRC_ABCD` into console message or how do I get to print the query `SELECT * FROM ABCD`?Anybody have any info about this?

Answer (score 0):

A function that returns ref cursor is maybe simpler to use:

```
SQL> create table abcd as
  2    select employee_id, first_name, salary from employees
  3    where rownum <= 5;

Table created.

SQL> create or replace function f_abcd
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    cur_r sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open cur_r for select * from abcd;
  7    return cur_r;
  8  end;
  9  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_abcd from dual;
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1
        100 Steven                    24000
        101 Neena                     17000
        102 Lex                       17000
        103 Alexander                  9000
        104 Bruce                      6000
```

However, if you have to use a procedure, then you'd do something like this:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_abcd (par_out out sys_refcursor)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    open par_out for select * from abcd;
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> var l_out refcursor;
SQL> begin p_abcd(:l_out); end;
  2  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :l_out
        100 Steven                    24000
        101 Neena                     17000
        102 Lex                       17000
        103 Alexander                  9000
        104 Bruce                      6000

SQL>
```

Unfortunately, that's where I reach my limits; I don't know anything about C# nor asp.net so I can't help with showing you how to use the above code in those languages. Sorry.

Comment: hi thanks for reply :). i will try your way to print the stored procedure output.